# (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found.', None, 0, -2147221233), None) - error in outlook

Tags: python, outlook

I'm currently working on moving mails to specific folder in outlook using pywin32.com python library.
I have to make the folder path to be configurable and hence I have created a python file where I keep the folder path as a list. The contents of FoldersConfig.py file is:

#folder names relative to inbox folder

```
mailBox = "mailbox-name"
nagiosDestinationFolder = ["Resolved_Clients","Internal","Nagios alerts"] #all these folders are been created in outlook with exact names.
```

Then there's another file to move mail to a destination folder. In my case **Nagios alerts** is my destination folder. Code snippet of MoveNagiosAlerts.py file is:

```
outlook = client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    stores = outlook.Stores
    for store in stores:
        mailBox = FoldersConfig.mailBox
        if(mailBox in store.DisplayName):
            rootFolder = store.GetDefaultFolder(6) #rootFolder is the Inbox folder
            break 
    
    def moveWarnings():
        print("Moving warning mails...")
        warnCount = 0
        scriptingDictionary = {}
        nagiosDestFolder = rootFolder
        for i in FoldersConfig.nagiosDestinationFolder:
            nagiosDestFolder = nagiosDestFolder.Folders(i)
        print(nagiosDestFolder)
        for i in range(rootFolder.Items.Count-1,0,-1):
            msg = rootFolder.Items[i]
            if(msg.Body.find("State: WARNING") != -1):
               msg.Move(nagiosDestFolder)
               warnCount+=1
        return warnCount
```

The error that is popped up when I run MoveNagiosAlerts.py file is:

```
Root folder(Inbox):  Inbox
Moving warning mails..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Documents\MoveNagiosAlerts.py", line 193, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Documents\MoveNagiosAlerts.py", line 172, in main
    warningsCount = moveWarnings()
  File "C:\Users\Documents\MoveNagiosAlerts.py", line 56, in moveWarnings
    nagiosDestFolder = nagiosDestFolder.Folders(i)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 181, in __call__
     return self._get_good_object_(self._oleobj_.Invoke(*allArgs),self._olerepr_.defaultDispatchName,None)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found.', None, 0, -2147221233), None)
```

[Outlook folder structure for your refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9fWs.png)

**My question is Why is this error thrown?? It sometimes works fine but most of the time this error is thrown. Any idea what is exactly wrong in my code?? or is it the outlook's problem?**

As per my understanding I think the pywin client is not able to get the folder that is in the list. But not sure whether that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the following loop in the code:

```
for i in range(rootFolder.Items.Count-1,0,-1):
            msg = rootFolder.Items[i]
```

When items are moved the number of items in the collection is decreased. So, you need to be prepared for that.

Also if you want to move only items that correspond to the condition you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods to get such items and them move all of them without checking any other properties. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Thank you for taking time and answering my question @Eugene Astafiev. "rootFolder.Items.Count" takes the current number of items count in the inbox if I'm not wrong. The two links were very helpful. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciating my answer is going to be a little vague but I did this on a company computer and ofc I can't quite share code directly from work, however:
It took me ages to figure that pywin32.com handles the itemCollection different than VBA itself - which is to say the overall logic described towards the end of [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.findnext) (in particular the VBA loop for moving items) doesn't directly translate into Python bcs VBA can handle a changed itemCollection, whereas pywin32 cannot.

You therefore need to create a `dictionary` with a k/v logic of relevant `EntryID`s ([read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.entryid)) and Folders (that should be obvious). In short, parse your folders (emails, that is) and add to the dict each `EntryID` plus folder combination, and then after that's done, loop through your emails one by one and move the relevant items as per dict.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34931448)